# Set up a bootstrap container for every view except one in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-4

I'm building a Rails app and I would like to use a bootstrap container for every view except one, the homepage. Ideally I would put the `yield` on application.html.erb inside the container so that it will include every view, but this would also be including the homepage. Is there an easy way to exclude only the homepage?

application.html.erb

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You can create a separate layout for that particular controller. link[https://medium.com/@kevinyckim33/rails-layout-rendering-cheatsheet-d40e14ab3503] This can help you out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an additional layout in your `app/views/layouts/` directory. Then use that layout for that action you need.

```
class YourController < ApplicationController 
  layout "your_new_layout", only: :your_action
  ...
end
```

Refer to [the documentation on Ruby on Rails Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) for additional information.

Comment: I don't think `:your_action` need to be in array ([source](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Layouts.html#module-ActionView::Layouts-label-Conditional+layouts)).

Comment: @TeWu, you are right as it's for a single action. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a separate layout as mentioned above or you just add an if statement into the view which excludes the controller and action like so:

```
<% unless params[:controller] == "pages" && params[:action] == "home" %>
<div class="container">
<% end %>
```

You always have access to the controller and action through the params.
Don't forget to also do that for the ending div.

I prefer this if it is just a small change to the acutal layout - but different layout makes more sense if there are a lot of changes.